# Internal Server Error While calling a Azure REST API from BAS : CF

Tags: sap-business-technology-platform, sap-business-application-studio

I am trying to call a Azure Rest API in a SAP UI5 Application from BAS via a Destination setup in BAS. I am getting 500- Internal Server error while executing the API call and no other error description.

My Destination is a OAuth2UserTokenExchange type destination for token based Authentication. The calls are getting resolved when we execute standalone from postman, but getting error while executing via destination.

Please find the screenshots for my destination and error below.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]